# Closing OS App Selector For Selenium on Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, selenium

I'm trying to automate joining a zoom meeting via browser (not with the actual zoom application) using selenium and chromedriver (via node.js), and have run into some issues with MacOS. Currently the program navigates to the join link, waits a second for the OS App Selector popup to appear, then presses Escape to close the popup (using node-key-sender package and then node-keys-simulator), clicks the LAUNCH MEETING button, then presses escape again, and finally presses the new Join From Your Browser link.

This process works on Windows, but for some reason Mac doesn't register the escape key. The same issue occurs when using tab and enter to navigate to the cancel button and press it.

Other posts suggest to modify the chrome setup to block the popup, but none of those have been able to work for me (which one post suggested was because Google had disabled the feature).

Does anyone have any suggestions how to bypass the OS App Selector popup, either with key presses or potentially via another modification to the chromedriver options?

Answer (score 0):

Realised that I could just completely avoid this screen by replacing the /j/ in the url with /wc/join/, which then gets redirected (with the password hashed and updated in the redirect) to point to the web-client join page